# Shell script to nullify a file everytime it reaches a specific size

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am in the middle of writing a shell script to nullify/truncate a file if it reaches certain size. Also the file is being opened/written by a process all the time. Now every time when I nullify the file, will the file pointer be repositioned to the start of the file or will it remain in its previous position? Let me know if we could reset the file pointer once the file has been truncated?

Comment: Maybe you just want `logrotate` which probably does what you want.

Comment: logrotate takes a backup right ? I just want to truncate it once it grows by certain size ..

Answer (score 2):

The position of the file pointer depends on how the file was opened by the process that has it open.  If it was opened in append mode, then truncating the file will mean that new data will be written at the end of the file, which is actually the beginning too the first time it writes after the file is truncated.  If it was not opened in append mode, then truncating the file will simply mean that there is a series of virtual zero bytes at the start of the file, but the real data will continue to be written at the same point as the last write finished.  If the file is being reopened by the other process, rather than being held open, then roughly the same rules apply, but there is a better chance that the file will be written at the beginning.  It all depends on how the first process to write to the file after the truncation is managing its file pointer.

You can't reset the file pointer of another process, AFAIK.

Comment: ok thanks for that, now how do we make the application write from the beginning of the file again ? any idea ?

Comment: You write the application so that it does what you want, or ask the maintainers to fix it as you want.  Should it truncate the file when it starts?  Using append mode is key for long running processes that will hold the file open for long periods of time (hours, days, ...).

Comment: I dont have any information about the app/process , it's taken care by a different offshore database team. How append will help truncating the file?

Comment: You can ask them about how they open their log file, though they may not choose to answer. If the file is opened in O_APPEND mode, then before each write, the o/s implicitly seeks to the EOF offset and starts to write there. If that happens to be at offset 0 because the file was truncated, so be it. If the file is not opened in O_APPEND mode, then the process writing has its file pointer at an offset of, say, 100 MiB. When it next goes to write, it will start writing at that point in the file. If you truncated the file, that means that all the bytes between offset 0 and 100 MiB will be zero.

Comment: You can even find out which it is by truncating the file while the process has it open.  If the file size stays large, then you have a problem; if it shrinks as you want, you don't.  Just be careful to run the test a few times; if they closed and reopened the file, you might see truncation 'by accident'.  If you see the file staying large (and containing data added at the end), then it's close to definitive that the file is not opened in append mode; it is a reasonable enhancement request to ask them to ensure that the log file is opened in append mode.

Comment: thank you so much, i will check the file mode and see if that helps me.

Answer (score 0):

A cron job or something like this will do the task; it will find every files bigger than 4096bytes then nullified the files

```
$ find -type f -size 4096c -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do cat /dev/null > $line; done
```

[enter link description here](https://superuser.com/a/204571/234312)